# DateTime list column with 1 minute increments in sharepoint

Tags: datetime, sharepoint, minute

I have created a datetime column in sharepoint. There we have minute increment of 5 minutes only. So that I could not enter the time in format 3:22 pm only 3:25 pm or 3:20 pm can only be entered. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

@FRECEENA FRANCIS,

Even though the increment is 5 minutes, you can change the time to minute intervals by typing it in and saving. It will hold the time to whatever you type in.

[image]

I tested it on SPO/SP2013, i believe it works for other SP versions.

BR